# Plotting contour map of modeled pollution data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapping

I'm a complete beginner to GIS, and I'm trying to create a filled contour map of pollutant concentration data for an area of NSW, Australia.

I've calculated the modeled concentrations of the pollutant as a value for each xy co-ordinate and need some help getting started plotting this as a contour map?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange!  Can you describe your data briefly; is it point vector (eg shapefile) or gridded raster? If it is point vector layer, [Contour](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/contour/) plugin would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose that you have a table in a CSV file, as follows:

```
X    Y    PM10
--   --    ----
```

Suppose that the name of the file is `kaddu.csv`

So I will first read the file:

```
A <- read.csv('kaddu.csv', header = T)
```

We will now load the `sp` and `gstat` libraries (I assume you have them installed).

```
library(sp) 
library(gstat)
```

We will now convert the data into a spatial data frame.

```
coordinates(A) = ~X + Y
```

We will now determine the X and Y ranges of the spatial data frame

```
x.range = range(A@coords[,1])
y.range = range(A@coords[,2])
```

We will now create a grid.

```
gridRes = 30
A.grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from=x.range[1], to=x.range[2], by = gridRes), 
               y = seq(from=y.range[1], to=y.range[2], by = gridRes))
coordinates(A.grd) = ~x + y
gridded(A.grd) = T
```

We will now run IDW interpolation

```
A.idw = idw(PM10 ~ 1, A, A.grd)
```

Now the last step, for image plot and contours.

```
spplot(A.idw["var1.pred"], contour = T, pretty = T)
```

Hope this helps.